# Can we ask questions in French about French universities?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a student in a French university. I have some questions about the French system and universities. May I ask it in French so it would be easier for me to express myself? And so French users may respond more precisely (maybe)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most sites *English language* is mandatory.
There are a few sites where you can ask about programming related or language specific problems in your native language so far.

It seems that you want to ask some stuff related to what [SE Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) is aimed for. Though the language should be *English* there.